# Excel - countif()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am having troubles with the excel function Countif.

I got 2 columns A and B and they should contain (almost) the same entries - which is what i am testing for and i need to know which entries are different. Order does not matter.

columns are actually tickers and look like this
http://pastebin.com/zHdJ5ndp

ok, so i use countif to identify the entries of column B which are not in column A.

```
Countif(A:A;B1)
Countif(A:A;B2)
...
```

The result is a column full of zeros, which is just not correct.

other simple tests like

```
a a 1
b b 1
c c 1
d d 1
e e 1
f f 1
g g 2
g h 0
```

work just fine!

What am I doing wrong right here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the data in column A and B is the same (no extra space etc)?

Comment: thanks, you are right! the first column had a extra space at the end. :-/

Comment: in that case you can do `=SUM((TRIM(A:A)=B1)*1)` and enter it as an array formula `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: thanks, i got this already. i just did not realize the whitespaces

Comment: perhaps better to remove the spaces - use Edit > Replace on column A replacing a space with nothing then the original COUNTIF should work

Comment: @assylias could you post is as an answer, so OP can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the data in column A and B is the same (no extra space etc)?